# Remove all data while keeping the Ubuntu

Tags: reset

I have an Ubuntu Latitude E6410 and for the past month and a half I have had other peoples data and online accounts on it. I don't want to remove something if it could cause any damage to the operating system. I also would like to know how to wipe the computer along with all the accounts and data (but with the Operating System perfectly safe) Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my suggestions:

1. First create a new user for yourself:

   ```
   sudo useradd -m newuser
   sudo passwd newuser
   ```
2. Then add yourself to `sudo` group:

   ```
   sudo gpasswd -a newuser sudo
   ```
3. logout from your user account and login with your new user.
4. now go to `/home` and remove everything except your new user's home directory, or use `userdel -r username` to remove other users.

Now all your data are gone however you have a running system with a freshly new user.

Comment: What about environment variables, aliases and other .deb packages installed in ```/opt``` and all other changes? is there any way to make ubuntu completely new